# 404 error setting up subdirectory in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm adding a subdirectory /blog onto my server which is a wordpress installation.

I've setup the following config on nginx but getting a 404 error on /blog. The rest of the site/config is working perfectly.

What am I missing?

domain.com

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    server_name domain.com;

    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
 }

server {
    listen 443  ssl;
    server_name domain.com;

    ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/domain_com-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/domain_com.key;

    root /opt/domain.com/public/;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

      location /blog {
        root /var/www/html/siteWordpress/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
      }

      location / {
        try_files $uri @backend;
      }

       location @backend {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }

}
```

Comment: What does `error.log` tell? What is the location of your Wordpress `index.php` in your filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress uses PHP and currently you have PHP set up for the document root `/opt/domain.com/public/`, but not for the document root `/var/www/html/siteWordpress/`.

You need to add a nested location block:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    root /var/www/html/siteWordpress/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    location ~ \.php$ { ... }
}
```

The `^~` modifier is necessary to make the prefix location take precedence over other regular expression locations at the same level. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

The default URI on the `try_files` statement should be prefixed by `/blog` otherwise the wrong `index.php` will be executed.

The above assumes that WordPress is installed under `/var/www/html/siteWordpress/blog/`, if this is not the case, your configuration just got a lot more complicated.

WordPress needs to know that it is hosted in a subdirectory, for example, by adding the following to `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/blog');
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. Almost there! The files are visible, yet the php files aren't being processed, just downloaded by the browser. The error log is giving me this: FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,

Comment: That error almost always means that SCRIPT_FILENAME is not set to the correct value.

Comment: It's currently: $document_root$fastcgi_script_name